Spring & Keycloak login without credentials
We have a system with the following components:
System A: A Spring backend, Angular SPA, and Keycloak for authentication.
System B: Another application with its own authentication mechanism.
Every user from System B will also be registered in System A's Keycloak (though there will be users in System A who are not in System B).
Problem:
When a user is logged into System B and is redirected to System A, I want them to be automatically authenticated in System A without needing to log in again.
In other words, how can I create a session in Spring + Keycloak for this user in System A without knowing their password?
Attempted Solution:
I tried using Keycloak's token exchange mechanism to obtain an access token, but the generated access token doesn’t seem sufficient to fully mimic a normal login session in System A.
Question:
How can I set up automatic authentication in System A for users coming from System B without needing to know their password?

What you are asking seems to be SSO between A & B. I'm not sure you can achieve this without modifying B to use OAuth2 and the same realm as A for user authentication.

users from systemB, what they use to authenticate? you could configure inside keycloak too

A possible solution:
Precondition:

User logs in to system B.
System B does something, and redirects to system A. The redirect to a dedicated endpoint.

OIDC flow:

System A redirects the user again to system B, starting an OIDC authentication (maybe with a special scope), e.g., a special authentication flow just for the keycloak-client system A. The special authentication flow only checks if the current user is known to the system B (e.g., cookie)
System B redirects user back to system A including a code.
System A fetches the access- and ID token from system B via /token endpoint.
System A processes token, checks all necessary claims if they are present and valid.

Post-flow:

System A creates new/updates existing user in system A, and logs user in.

